# Winforms  запретить ввод символов в textbox

Tags: c#, text, winforms, visual-studio, usercontrol

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какое нибудь свойство у textbox, которое бы запрещала пользователю вводить буквы туда, т.е. что бы можно было только цифры вводить туда(в том числе и с запятой)? Или может есть не свойство, а специальный элемент для этой цели?

Comment: А если обработать событие по нажатию на кнопки и вместо некорректных символов просто ничего не вводить , точнее "/0" ?

Comment: Почитай книжку Visual C# - задачах и примерах. Н.Культин. У него вначале книге, есть хорошие примеры по поводу запрещения букв и лишних запятых. Для Winforms. Код хороший.

Answer (score 6):

Обычно рекомендуют [masked textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx), альтернативно можно [фильтровать ввод](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073517/2908793), хотя обычно это необходимо для расширенного управления вводом (плюс в этом случае нужно следить за копипастингом).

(сам, правда, с C# немного другими делами занимался)

Answer (score 2):

Для ввода цифр можно использовать элемент управления NumericUpDown, либо фильтровать ввод в текстбокс обрабатывая событие `KeyPress`, например так:

```
  private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || 
            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && e.KeyChar == ','))
        {
            return;
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: В таком случае надо не забыть выключить обработку хот-кеев, иначе ни какого смысла в такой фильтрации ввода, по ctrl+v туда можно ввести все что угодно.